# How can I create a master-agent setup for Mesos on seperate VM’s

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtual-machine, mesos

We have been trying to establish a working mesos environment distributed in two machines – one that will run the master and another that will run the agent (slave). The steps that we have followed so far are:

1. We have compiled the latest version of the mesos code (1.1.0) successfully following the instructions at https://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/.
2. We have deployed a master and an agent on an Ubuntu 16.04 VM (let’s call this VM A) .
3. We tried to execute the three example frameworks listed at the end of the mesos getting started guide, and the python/java frameworks are successful. However the C++ framework failed.
4. We then deployed an agent on another Ubuntu 16.04 VM (VM B) of the same architecture and stopped the running agent on VM A. The mesos-master properly takes into account the resources offered by B.
5. Finally, we tried to execute the frameworks on VM B. However, all of the tasks failed, as the agent kept re-registering, and the tasks kept getting lost (while there was definitely no issue about network connectivity) before even starting. There was no lack of resources.

The same procedure was repeated on a virtualbox network of two Ubuntu 14.04 machines that were able to communicate to each other freely. This setup was based on the mesos packages recommended by the apache aurora project, in this document:

https://aurora.apache.org/documentation/latest/operations/installation

We experimented altering the config files in `/etc/mesos/`, `/etc/mesos-master/`, `/etc/mesos-slave/`, `/etc/defaults/mesos`, `/etc/defaults/mesos-master`, `/etc/defaults/mesos-slave`, and finally the master being able to take into account the resources, but unable to launch any tasks if the agent was running in a different machine.

Can anyone that has managed to successfully setup mesos, give a hint about a complete 2-node mesos master-agent setup for Ubuntu machines in a private network? Which extra runtime parameters are needed, and which configuration files must be altered (and how) so as to get at least the example frameworks running on an external VM?

Comment: Can you post a log? I suspect you need to configure IPs Mesos is broadcasting so VMs can communicate.

Comment: Thank you janisz. It is not possible to post the log, but where could this configuration be altered? Is it one of the files posted above that we should modify? Do you agree with the procedure followed?